# Sharing a link in android

Tags: android

I have developed an ecomerce app. I would like to develop share feature similar to flipkart app.

I open a particular product on flipkart app. There they have share button I click on share I get the following link:

http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/united-colors-benetton-sneakers/p/itmee2ahxjhz3pbz?pid=SHOEE2AHDGPBFFZ8&cmpid=product.share.pp

When I click the link this opens a dialog box like below:

[image]

If I click on flipkart it automatically opens that product on the app or if I choose browser it opens the website automatically.

How is this done? I would like to know the logic? Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try Something Like this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="www.android.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: what will this do?  How can this help me to open my APP to show the required product?

Comment: Can you please give more details on this?

Comment: What details you need?

Comment: I would like know how does this work? I mean do I need write a service / broadcastreceiver to open the App with correct product details?